# divided tag between text with ";"

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

how can I add `";"` a separator between each text from the row? actually, I used `';'` join, but it doesn't work well, it including within tag text `"FRI 1"`, I want to separate into `"FRI"` and `"1"`.

```
# -*- coding:UTF-8 -*-
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("url")
table = ['; '.join([j.text for j in i.find_elements_by_class_name('couponRow') if j.text]) for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="todds"]//div[@class="couponTable"]') if i.text]
for line in table:
    print line
driver.close()
```

expected result:

```
Friday Matches; 
FRI ;1 ; Uruguay; vs; France; Expected In Play start selling time: ; 06/07 ; 22:00 ; 4.75 ; 2.92 ; 1.78
FRI ;2 ; Brazil; vs; Belgium; Expected In Play start selling time: ; 07/07 ; 02:00 ; 1.94 ; 3.05 ; 3.70
Saturday Matches ; 
SAT ;1 ; Sweden; vs; England; Expected In Play start selling time: ; 07/07 ; 22:00 ; 5.10 ; 2.95 ; 1.73
SAT ;2 ; Russia; vs; Croatia; Expected In Play start selling time: ; 08/07 ; 02:00 ; 3.85 ; 2.70 ; 2.07
```

Comment: That list comprehension is not easy to understand. Simple is better than complex.

Comment: you need to split that text with space. `j.text.split(' ')`

Comment: @ManojJadhav `split()` uses whitespace by default. `j.text.split()` will suffice.

Comment: dears  , got some error "TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, list found"

Comment: You need to do this `"; ".join(j.text.split(" "))`. This will sort your issue.

Comment: dears  , lines = ['; '.join(j.text.split()) for j in i.find_elements_by_class_name('couponRow') if j.text) for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="todds"]//div[@class="couponTable"]') if i.text] , am i correct ? but it not work !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will add semi-colon in the spaces for each line, You can further customize to remove the semicolon between the Monday;Matches and Expected;In;Play;start;selling;time:

```
import sys
    from selenium import webdriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/vbabu/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get("url")
    for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="todds"]//div[@class="couponTable"]'):
        for j in i.find_elements_by_class_name('couponRow'):
            print(';'.join([item for item in j.text.split(' ')]))
    driver.close()
```

**Output:**

```
Monday;Matches
MON;41;HammarbyvsOstersunds;Expected;In;Play;start;selling;time:
10/07;01:00;1.85;3.50;3.35
Tuesday;Matches
TUE;1;FrancevsBelgium;Expected;In;Play;start;selling;time:
11/07;02:00;2.38;2.82;2.95
Wednesday;Matches
WED;1;CroatiavsEngland;Expected;In;Play;start;selling;time:
12/07;02:00;3.45;2.80;2.15
```

Comment: thanks, dears, but it not my expected, thanks again!

Comment: @Mary Are you looking for the expected output in Question ?

Comment: min2bro  ,  dears, yes, since i've some difficult on this issues, thanks !

Comment: @Mary You are not extracting the text correctly , their are multiple class within the countrow div, extract it separately and join it by ';' .These are the classes: cday,cflag,cteams,cvenue,ctv,cesst,codds,codds,codds

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using split

```
# -*- coding:UTF-8 -*-
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://bet.hkjc.com/football/odds/odds_inplay.aspx?lang=EN")
table = ['; '.join(["; ".join( j.text.split(" ")) for j in i.find_elements_by_class_name('couponRow') 
if j.text]) for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//* 
 [@id="todds"]//div[@class="couponTable"]') if i.text]
for line in table:
    print line
driver.close()
enter code here
```

Comment: thanks, dears, but it not my expected, thanks again!